# How many data does Firebase read in these use-cases

Tags: firebase

I am creating a chat app, initially I will start (or try) using the free Firebase plan, which allows up to 50.000 readings per day. The app lists conversations, and when you open a conversation, messages appear in a list, retrieved from the realtime database firebase.

1. If the user opens a conversation that has 1.000 messages, will 1.000 readings be counted?
2. When `onStop` is called in the message activity, I remove the `valueEventListener` listener from messages. So if the user closes the message screen and reopens 50 times, will 50.000 readings be generated and the free plan reaches the limit?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: I answered both questions below, but in the future please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. If the user opens a conversation that has 1.000 messages, will 1.000 readings be counted?

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't count the number of messages you read. You might be confusing it with Cloud Firestore if you think so.

The Firebase Realtime Database charges based on the amount of data that is sent from the server to the various listeners on clients. So if you listen for all 1000 messages, you will be charged for the amount of data of all 1000 messages. But if you for example create a query that only listens to the last 100 messages, you will only be charged for the amount of data transferred for those 100 messages.

> 2. When onStop is called in the message activity, I remove the valueEventListener listener from messages. So if the user closes the message screen and reopens 50 times, will 50.000 readings be generated and the free plan reaches the limit?

This depends on how you configured your app. By default the data is only kept in memory for as long as a listener is attached to that data. So that means if you attach the last/only listener, the data is removed from memory, and indeed it will have to be reloaded from the server when you attach a new listener.

You can however enable disk persistence in the client, which means it persists data to a disk cache in addition to keeping it in memory. The behavior when you detach the listener is the same: it is removed from memory. But when you attach a new listener, the Firebase client will first load the data it has in the disk cache in this case, and then ask the server for only the data that has changed. This typically reduces data transfer a lot, but it's hard to say how much precisely.

Note that disk persistence combine well with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, so you should only use it if you're using `addChildEventListener` or `addValueEventListener`. Those are by far the most idiomatic way to get data from Firebase anyway, so any change to use this will likely be beneficial for your user experience too.